# Alamofire Swift get html source

Tags: html, swift, alamofire

I just want to retrieve the html source from a simple website.

```
@IBAction func scan_func(sender: AnyObject) {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.example.com")
            .response { request, response, data, error in
                print(request)
                print(response)
                print(data)
        }
    }
```

I already have successfully added "App Transport Security Settings" and "Allow Arbitrary Loads" to info.plist to load http content.

When I run that code I only get an output like this:
[XCODE - hexadecimal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPVF9.png)
I hope you can help me.

kind regards

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are printing out the raw bytes of the data. I'm guessing you are looking for a way to print out the corresponding string representation.
You could for instance do this with Alamofire's provided closure:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.example.com")
    .responseString { response in
        print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
}
```

(Check out the documentation [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-string-handler))

Alternatively, you could convert the string yourself:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.example.com")
    .response { request, response, data, error in
        print(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
}
```

[Apple String reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1418413-init)