# Convert CURL to Swift for using in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, http, curl, alamofire

My CURL is

```
curl --header "secret: mytoken" --data "a=addPost&session=mySession&postBody=test" https://example.com/testing/
```

I want to use it with Alamofire. How to convert it to Swift code?

**Update.**

My code is:

```
@IBAction func postTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/testing/") else { return }

    let headers = [
        "secret": "mytoken"
    ]

    let parameters = [
        "a": "addPost",
        "session": "mySession",
        "postBody": "test"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(reason:
>   Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error:
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around
>   character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around
>   character 0.}))

**Update 2.**

When I use this CURL in mac os terminal I got the correct JSON:

```
{"result":100,"data":{"id":"mydata"}
```

But in `swift` code I got error.

Comment: Did you [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+curl+alamofire)? There are almost 100 related questions

Comment: I am update my question

Comment: The error says that the returned data is not JSON. Print the received data as string to see what you get. You might tell the server that the data type is JSON.

Comment: I am get HTML...

Comment: When I use CURL in mac os terminal I get correct JSON.

Comment: Which format do you expect, JSON or HTML?

Comment: I expect JSON format

Comment: Does the HTML you obtained contain an error message?

You can get HTML string like this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421011/alamofire-swift-get-html-source

Comment: No, it is simple HTML with the task description

Comment: @Larme your post is answer of my question!

Answer (score 1):

```swift
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "a": "addPost",
    "session": "mySession",
    "postBody": "test"
]

let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "secret": "mytoken"
]

Alamofire.request("https://example.com/testing/", parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I am update my question. It is not working

Comment: Your server side is not returning Valid Json.

Comment: When I use CURL in mac os terminal I get correct JSON. But in code I get this error...

Answer (score 1):

Solution - use URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody)(thx Larme):

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody), headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
    print(response)
}
```

Comment: You could either update my answer on the other question, and/or mark yours as duplicate at that one.

Comment: I am up vote your answer in this question